How to determine default HTML element native props
I'm currently using React with Typescript, and realize I can define the props for a component in such a way that extends the default properties of an HTML element, like so:
type TextInputProps = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & {
  label?: string
  description?: string
}

const TextInput = ({
  label,
  description,
  ...props
}: TextInputProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* omitting unnecessary code */}
      <input
        className={`flex-shrink:0  border-gray-3 border-radius: 0.25rem h-9 w-full rounded`}
        {...props}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

However I'm clueless as to where I can find such interfaces like React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> to use when I create other components using native HTML elements.
Is there documentation for something like this, or a cheat sheet online? I want quick and easy access, because I know I speak for other developers when I say I won't be able to remember half of these interfaces names hahaha.
Thanks

actually, React provides helper type for this, that is very easy to use
type MyInputProps = ComponentProps<"input"> & { label: string};
type MyButtonProps = ComponentProps<"button"> & { label: string};

you can use it even for existing components
import {SomeComponent} from some/library;

type MyCustomProps = ComponentProps<typeof SomeComponent> & {myprop: boolean}


I think thats not exactly what you want, because its not list of interfaces, but it might help :)

btw, found that list here :)

Not exactly what I'm looking for, but I'll be sure to use it because it seems very useful. Thanks for linking that list also, that solves my question!
